# Firefox Addon (SDK) -- Is there a way to get a text hover-over response with minimal script injection

Tags: javascript, sdk, firefox-addon

I'm working with the Firefox Addon SDK writing a Spanish dictionary addon. What I want to do is have a dictionary pop up with the translation when the mouse hovers over text. No highlighting the text or right-clicking should be required (although some dictionaries use this). There are several programs that do this with the old addon XUL format (Rikaichan among others), but I was wondering if there was a way to do this with the new SDK.

My current workaround is to inject javascript tags around every word in the text nodes along with onmouseover="lookThisUp()". This works, but it runs into complications when I want to check words that change meaning when in pairs ("get up" rather than "get"), so a method without cutting up all the text with javascript tags would be preferential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an example of how to do it with the most recent navigator:browser window:

```
var {Cu} = require('chrome');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var aDOMWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
aDOMWindow.gBrowser.addEventListener('mouseover', isTextNode, true);
function isTextNode(event) {
  var node = event.explicitOriginalTarget;
  if (node.nodeName == '#text') {
    Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log('moused over a text node = ',node,'the event:',event);
  }
}
```

as you mouse over things in the most recent browser if its over a textnode it will log it to Browser Console.

Comment: I had to do my HW on XPCOM and got the code working by adding
`const {Cu} = require("chrome");`
`Services = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm").Services;`
but I couldn't get
`Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log('moused over a text node = ',node,'the event:',event);`
to log anything to the browser console. I could log to command prompt though with
`console.log(....)`
Node is logging as an empty array, but even if the code were working, I have a feeling it would be returning the full node and not the exact word I would be hovering over. Is that right?

Comment: my code works man and because im getting event.explicitOriginalTarget it will give you the text node. see image here: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v135/noitidart/my20code20works_zpsdd244f45.png

Comment: I was assuming web console = browser console. My bad. Code works, but is there a way to get it to return the exact word I am over rather than only the node.

Comment: for that you will have to use do some calculation. the deepest target is node. so use the events mouse x and y, and then calculate what letter in the node is right under the mouse, and then from that letter go right and left till you find a non-word character and that's your word. this sounds interesting ill try to write something for you sometime soon, if i forget please remind me.

Comment: Actually this explanation is the answer I was looking for. It's a bit more complicated than I want to implement, so I'll stick with my workaround. I did learn a lot about XPCOM and will have to come to playing around with it when I get more time. Your code actually is perfect for another addon I was hoping to make so I'll be putting it to use. Thanks!

Comment: Cool man :) Whats your work around to get the word the mouse is over? I'm interested now too haha

Comment: by replacing every word with
`text = text.replace(/(\W)(\w+)/g, '$1<element onmouseover="sendWord(\'$2\')">$2</element>');`
and sending the word using 
`port.emit("word", word)`
I'm still fighting with TreeWalker to get a clean way to insert the html. My workaround for multiple word lookups is to change the dictionary entry to include those multiple word uses as well (since there aren't so many)

Comment: Ahhhhh that's a hacky work around haha nice man. You are doing this just to the node that gets moused over right not the whole document?

Comment: I'm doing it to every text node. Actually, this would then make every word a child text node, so I could just do that---make every word it's own node and use your example (I realized that as I was going to bed last night...). However making everything it's own node (and only relying on that characteristic) is not easily reversible if I want to turn the dictionary off (and return the page completely to as it was before) but I guess that can be done with counters and flags in the addon script.

Comment: ok man so this is what you do. on mouseover a text node. clone that node. and then turn all the words in that textnode to a word. dont use regex it gets real slow. just split the textnode based on a space (or simple regex pttern of \W). then do your magic on that clonedNode, this way you don't bother the main document. in case of unisntall.

Comment: Ah, I was overthinking it--trying to be sure I can wipe it clean. Better just to keep a clean copy.

Comment: I want to do this sometime so this is a note to myself. This function should be helpful: [document.caretPositionFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.caretPositionFromPoint)